# Users Cannot See Other Users on Leaderboard Component of Salesforce Community

Tags: community

We're using Community Templates, Napili. We've implemented the Leaderboard component. We implemented a sharing set so users can only see other users' chatter posts if they fall under the same account. This works fine however, they can't see each other on leaderboard, only a few (some of which are under different accounts).

Internal users can see the full list of 10 users on Leaderboard though our external profiles aren't able to. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Best,
Kevin

[image: Leaderboard]

Answer (score 1):

Check Sharing Settings/ OWD on User, the default external access on User is Private and it sounds like this is your issue.